# check login using linq windows forms

Tags: c#, linq

i try to do some thing like If admin do some thing and if user do some thing

i am new in Linq to sql i think is better than ado 
now i used that 
my db table login_tb
**login_user, 
login_PWD,
login_Type**

```
public bool IsValidUser(string userName, string passWord)
    {
        using (db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            var s = from q in db.Login_TBs
                    where q.Login_User == txtuser.Text.ToString()
                    && q.Login_PWD == txtpwd.Text.ToString()
                    select q;
            if (s.Any())
            {

                return true;
            }
            else
            {

                return false;
            }
        }
    }
but how can i use login_type >>>>
```

Comment: what is login type ?? whta you want to do here in this function exaplin please

Comment: Add code inside the first if block if (s.First().Login_Type == "Admin") { ... } else {... } return true;